# How to perform operations on certain rows of one np array based on conditions of another np array using numpy methods?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example, I have one np array `A = [[30, 60, 50...], [ 15, 20, 18...], [21, 81, 50...]...]` of size `(N, 10)`.

And I have another np array `B = [1, 1, 0...]` of size `(N, )`.

I want to do operations E.g. I want all the sums of each column in A but only for rows where B==1. How would I do that without using any loops and just numpy methods?

So if I want sum of columns in A for indices where B == 1:

result = 30 + 15 because the first two indices in B are 1 but the third index is 0 so I wouldn't include it in the sum.

Comment: Please add a full input and the expected output

Comment: First question the example A provided isn't `(N,10)`. Seconds, according to your logic that B will determine rows then `B = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0...]` with B==1 means `[sum(1st row), sum(4th row), ...` right?

Comment: @Epsi95 I meant to show that each element of A is has more than 3 elements up to 10 with the "..." Sorry if wasn't clear.

Comment: Please see edit to where I've tried to make it more clear with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.compress`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) and `sum` along axis=0

```
>>> A = [[30, 60, 50], [ 15, 20, 18], [21, 81, 50]]
>>> B = [1, 1, 0]
>>> np.compress(B, A, axis=0).sum(0)
array([45, 80, 68])
```

If array, use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) on `B`:

```
>>> A = np.array([[30, 60, 50], [ 15, 20, 18], [21, 81, 50]])
>>> A[np.nonzero(B)].sum(0)
array([45, 80, 68])
```

Another way:

```
>>> A[B.astype(bool)].sum(0)
array([45, 80, 68])
```

If you want `0`s:

```
>>> np.compress(B==0, A, axis=0).sum(0)
# Or,
>>> A[np.nonzero(B==0)].sum(0)
# Or,
>>> A[~B.astype(bool)].sum(0)
```

If you want both `1`s and `0`s, obviously:

```
>>> A.sum(0)
```

Comment: This only returns values where B == 1. What if I also want values where B == 0?

Comment: @mha added at the end.

Comment: Hi, hope you won't mind another question. What if I don't want to sum but I just want to extract all the rows of A where B==1 so I can later do mean or std operations? So if B has 100 items that are 1, my new extracted array will also have 100 items.

Comment: @mha remove the `.sum(0)` at the end.

Comment: If I have ```n1 = np.compress(train_labels, train_features, axis=0)``` And I want to get std of just the first column of n1 how could I get it? I tried ```np.std(n1[0])``` but that's not correct. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `np.std(n1[:,0])`. If you have any further questions, you can ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `B` to `bool` type and mask `A`. Then you can get the `sum` along columns.

```py
A = np.array([[30, 60, 50], [ 15, 20, 18], [21, 81, 50]])
B = np.array([1, 1, 0])

A[B.astype(np.bool)].sum(axis=0)
```

```
array([45, 80, 68])
```

Comment: Rather than dumping code, consider adding text to explain why this answers the question. It doesn't have to be much to drastically improve your answer.

Comment: Certainly my please @Oliver Oliver